# De-serialize byte array to JSON

Tags: c#, json, rest

I have a WCF implemented with REST to get and return JSONs and I am trying to call its methods from a winform app.

I am checking on Fiddler to know whether I am being able to send the data or not and if I get a response.

Everything looks fine, I am sending a JSON to the web service and I am getting back a JSON..the problem is when I try to de-serialize it..

The returned JSON looks like :

[image]

So as you  can see I am getting data ** data returned**..I just dont know how to read it.
I am trying the following :

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(wcfPicture), null, int.MaxValue, false, true, null, null);
    byte[] res1 = WC.UploadData(ServiceUrl + "newImage", "POST", MS.ToArray());
    var stream = new MemoryStream(res1);
    var deserializedObjectXml = serializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

This is throwing me : There was an error deserializing the object of type wcfPicture. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

I am also trying :

```
    byte[] res1 = WC.UploadData(ServiceUrl + "newImage", "POST", MS.ToArray());
                    Stream res2 = new MemoryStream(res1);
                    JSrz = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(wcfPicture));
wcfPicture pI2 = (wcfPicture)JSrz.ReadObject(res2);
```

But the problem is that pI2 values are the default values of each property type..the strings are equal to "" and the integers are equal to 0..so I dont know what is actually going on..

Any help?

Comment: what encoding is your response in?

Comment: Do any of the `DataMember` attributes on the properties on `wcfPicture` have the `Name` property set (possibly differently than the names of the properties in the response)?

Comment: I checked and I named the properties of my local wcfPicture object to resemble the ones defined as dataMember in the WCF.

Comment: Does DataContractSerializer support JSON? I thought you needed a [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx) for that.